# Error while using Windows.Storage namespace

Tags: c#, oop, load, save

I am trying to save the string into a text file in my temp folder but i have this error:

```
Error2'await' requires that the type 'Windows.Foundation.IAsyncAction' have a 
suitable GetAwaiter method. Are you missing a using directive for 'System'
```

Thanks

P.S. this is C# console app.

My Code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Windows.Storage;

public static class Storage
{

    public static async void SaveData()
    {
        string myString = "This is the data I want to save";
        ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;

        // Add:  using Windows.Storage;
        Windows.Storage.StorageFolder localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder;

        // Optionally overwrite any existing file with CreationCollisionOption
        StorageFile file = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync("mySaveFile.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        try
        {
            if (file != null)
            {
                await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, myString);
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            // Error saving data
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're missing a .dll
Add a reference to this assembly:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5.1\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll

This is necessary for desktop app to use the extension method "GetAwaiter" from WinRT API.